# How to replicate session and cache data of an application server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, replication, rails-activerecord, application-server

I am looking appropriate resources on "how to replicate session (user session in a stateful app) and cached objects (retrieved from an underlying database through transactional operations) of an application server". The app server can preferably Rails or any other popular one which fully supports MVC framework (using ActiveRecord or DataMapper design patterns).

It will be also helpful to know similar thing about Memcached replication internals as well if it supports this kind of replication.

If anyone can further suggest on how to integrate a NoSQL key-value stores to keep session and cached objects generated in an app server like Rails that would another appreciated answer.

My goal is to find out suitable way to replicate an app server instance for performance (either for local users or geo-distributed) and high-availability. Any point-out to current industry practice and available solutions will be much helpful in this regard.

Thanks a lot in advance.